# call method name and body from sql server

Tags: c#

i want to call a method using MethodInfo and MethodBody Class of System.Reflection and the name and body of the method is in sql server how can i do that please help

```
         SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GlobalData.GetConnectionString());
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select CodeSnippet from SubMenu where Role_ID='"+GlobalData.RoleID+"' and ChildMenu='"+sender.ToString()+"'", con);
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                string codeSnippet = reader["CodeSnippet"].ToString();
                Type type = typeof(Helper);
                MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(codeSnippet);

                Helper c = new Helper();
                method.Invoke(c, null);
            }
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
```

i have done with this now i want the method body from the microsoft sql server

Comment: This is *terrifying*. Your statement is prone to SQL injection, **and** you're allowing methods to be dynamically executed based on some database value?

Comment: Why don't you edit your previous question [call method body from sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271359/call-method-body-from-sql-server) instead of creating a new one?

Comment: my previous question was not clear to explain @Nolonar

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly advise against allowing arbitrary code snippets to be executed on a production server; there is a good risk of bugs or malicious code doing very bad things. If you can, I would say that keeping the code in *your project*, and just referencing it by some kind of key (could be a name, but any unique identifier would suffice) - i.e. run the "LanuchTheMissiles" operation, where "LaunchTheMissles" is defined either in an enum or on a class explicitly designed to be the recipient of such operations.

If you **really really** want to go with snippets, then C# might not be the most convenient snippet language - although it can be done via [CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.compileassemblyfromsource.aspx). However, there are tools that are *designed* to be used with script languages - IronPython, etc. You could [embed IronPython pretty easily](http://www.secretgeek.net/host_ironpython.asp) if you're happy to use a different language. This, however, still has most of the risks associated with executing arbitrary code.

If the snippets are going to be provided by your developers, I would say: just put the code in the main project instead.

If the snippets are going to be provided by your users, I would say: don't; just don't.

Also: your SQL is asking for injection.

Comment: now i have some idea to follow from your explanation...Thank You Again Sir @Marc Gravell